# Amazon Fine Foods: Convert text file to pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have data in a text file in this format.

[image: Text File Screen Shot]

I want to read it as a `pandas dataframe`.  It should look like this

[image: Example Data Frame]

Original data with a text example here https://snap.stanford.edu/data/web-FineFoods.html

I have tried `df = pd.read_csv('/Users/aaronbroderick/Desktop/finefoods_text.txt', delimiter = '\t', encoding = 'latin_1')`.

Comment: And what is problem?

Comment: The data is in a text format.  I want to read it as a panda dataframe.  I don't  know what delimiter to use, or if there is another trick to get it to read it as a data frame

Comment: Could you open the text file and print the first few lines? That way, you can tell what delimiter is used

Comment: If you follow the link to the SNAP site, it is there

Comment: @AaronBroderick file size more than 100mb. provide sample data by yourself

Comment: I mean if you scroll to the bottom of the SNAP link, there is a text example that is probably more useful than what I can provide.

Comment: Ok, I uploaded a screenshot of my text file.  Hope that helps.

Comment: @AaronBroderick try this to read a file, df=pd.read_csv('foods.txt',sep='\n|:',header=None)

Comment: I'm getting this.  ParserWarning: Falling back to the 'python' engine because the 'c' engine does not support regex separators (separators > 1 char and different from '\s+' are interpreted as regex); you can avoid this warning by specifying engine='python'.

Comment: Also getting this.  Expected 2 fields in line 568502, saw 3. Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used.

Answer (score 0):

I've downloaded a file you mentioned, and could read it to DataFrame with 568455 records and 13 columns with this code:

```
import pandas as pd
with open('finefoods.txt','r', encoding='latin-1') as f:
    data = f.read()
df=pd.DataFrame([
    {line.split(': ')[0]:': '.join(line.split(': ')[1:]) 
     for line in record.split('\n')}
    for record in data.split('\n\n')])
```

as far as I know there are no built-in readers in pandas for such a format.

Updated:
Cleaning and validating such a large dataset indeed could require some efforts and creative approach. E.g. one of the source of extra unwanted column was this record:

```
product/productId: B002RIZUQ2
review/userId: AS2DLXUWDK0GP
review/profileName: MABEL "Tell us about yourself!
88 years old. ...
review/helpfulness: 1/1
review/score: 4.0
review/time: 1289088000
review/summary: delicious
```

It is leads to introducing "fake" column with name "88 years old. ..."

If it is ok to just ignore such malformed records, you could modify the code as follows.

```
import pandas as pd
with open('finefoods.txt','r', encoding='latin-1') as f:
    data = f.read()
columns_list=['product/productId',
 'review/helpfulness',
 'review/profileName',
 'review/score',
 'review/summary',
 'review/text',
 'review/time',
 'review/userId']

df=pd.DataFrame([
    {line.split(': ')[0]:': '.join(line.split(': ')[1:]) 
     for line in record.split('\n') if line.split(': ')[0] in columns_list}
    for record in data.split('\n\n')])
```

Now it is 8 columns and still 568455 records.

Comment: This seems to work, though there are 13 columns and there are supposed to be 8.  I used this code to fix that, but I cannot confirm/deny data loss.  df = df[['product/productId','review/helpfulness','review/profileName','review/score','review/summary','review/text','review/time','review/userId']]

Comment: It would be awesome to have the column titles not have review/ before every entry.

Comment: Of course it is possible to handle cases like mentioned above in more clever way (e.g. append orphaned lines it to latest column) but I think by going deeper we will go beyond the StackOverflow question/answer format, because it will be too specific and will be not interesting to any other readers of an answer. But if you have a questions about how the code works - just ask here, in comments.